# How can I submit the form?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-router, react-hooks

I am currently making a blog website with "reactjs".In this component, I am creating new blogs by putting values of author, title, and body.  I  cant submit the form by hitting 'Enter' on the keyboard on any fields.

This problem gets fixed when I remove my input field of author. Please guide me as I am new to Reactjs

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";

function Create() {
  const [title, setTitle] = useState();
  const [author, setAuthor] = useState();
  const [body, setBody] = useState();

  const submitFunc = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const blog = { title, body, author };
  };

  return (
    <div className="create container ">
      <form onSubmit={submitFunc}>
        <label className="text-danger" htmlFor="title">
          Title:
        </label>
        <input
          name="title"
          type="text"
          onChange={(e) => setTitle(e.target.value)}
          required
        />
        <label className="text-danger" htmlFor="body">
          Content:
        </label>
        <textarea
          onChange={(e) => setBody(e.target.value)}
          required
          name="body"
        ></textarea>
        <label className="text-danger" htmlFor="author">
          Author:
        </label>
        <input
          name="author"
          id="author"
          type="text"
          onChange={(e) => setAuthor(e.target.value)}
          required
        />
      </form>
      <p>{title}</p>
      <p>{author}</p>
      <p>{body}</p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Create;
```

Comment: author input is required so make sure you have a value in it. Also you need a button with type submit inside the form to be able to submit the form.

Comment: I do not want to add submit button . I just want to submit my form hitting enter key. Even if i put input of empty string in author it doesnt work I already tried it

Comment: yes, because submit button is required even if you want to use keyboard. Without a submit button (or disabled submit button), it's not possible to submit the form. If you want hide the submit button using css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the snippet you reported it is not clear how it should handle the `Enter` pressing.

If you want to do anything when the user presses `Enter` on any text area you can use the `onKeyPress` event handler.

```
const handleKeyPress = (e) => {
  if(e.keyCode === 13){
    e.preventDefault();

    // ...check title, boby and author exists
      
    const blog = { title, body, author };
      
    // ...submit the form
};


<textarea
  name="body"
  required
  onChange={(e) => setBody(e.target.value)}
  onKeyPress={handleKeyPress}
></textarea>
```